# AWS WAF + EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to setup some DDOS or webfiltering mechanism for the HTTP traffic that hits my EC2 instances. I do have around 40 AWS instances running various websites. I read about WAF ( https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) . This appears to be working on Load Balancer level. Do anyone know if I can set it up on my account level for filtering traffic to all my instances?

Answer (score 1):

The WAF service currently only works with load balancers and CloudFront distributions. It cannot be used if you aren't using one of those two services.

Comment: Is it necessary to associate the load balancer with WAF ACL that load balancer must have the HTTPS 443 in the security group?

Answer (score 0):

To keep updated, as of now, WAF can be associated with

1. CloudFront
2. Application Load Balancer (ALB)
3. Amazon API Gateway

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/waf/faqs/ (What services does AWS WAF support? and answer of it)